# Python script sending files as they come into the directory and email

Tags: python, email

Trying to create a piece of python code that monitors a directory for new randomly named csv files.
For some reason I cannot find a way to use the unix trick of *.cvs to work.
and then i need to have to particular file to be emailed and moved to a different directory.
this is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import base64
import smtplib
import mimetypes
import email
import email.mime.application
import shutil
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

#locate file and send it to the email
for file in os.listdir("/root/tmp/"):
   if file.endswith(".csv"):
     fromaddr = "FROM EMAIL"
     toaddr = "TO EMAIL"

     msg = MIMEMultipart()

     msg['From'] = fromaddr
     msg['To'] = toaddr
     msg['Subject'] = "CSV"

     body = "CSV SENT SUCCESSFULLY"

     msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

     filename = "prod.csv" # <-- trying to keep the file name from below as it finds it
     attachment = open("/root/tmp/prod.csv", "rb") # <--- need to send cvs as they come in

     part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
     part.set_payload((attachment).read())
     encoders.encode_base64(part)
     part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

     msg.attach(part)

     server = smtplib.SMTP('SMTP ADDRESS', 587)
     server.starttls()
     server.login(fromaddr, "PASSWORD")
     text = msg.as_string()
     server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
     server.quit()    

#move to a different folder once sent

     path = "/root/tmp/" # <--- using root for testing :)
     moveto = "/root/sent/" # <-- destination folder 
     files = os.listdir(path)
     files.sort()
     for f in files:
      src = path+f
      dst = moveto+f
      shutil.move(src,dst)
```

Comment: How do you intend to tell it to stop monitoring? It looks like it just runs once and exits, no monitoring going on.

Comment: Use [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for Unix style file matching.

Comment: In what way isn't the code working? Break it up into 4 parts, the monitoring, the name matching, the mailing, and the moving. Find out what doesn't work and ask a very specific question. See how to create a [mcve]. We don't know which part is the problem and everything else is a distraction.

Comment: it needs to run indefinitly in a loop. I would either have it on a loop or as a cron job.

Comment: I will see how to implement glob, as you can tell, this is one of my first python scripts :)

Comment: The last part of your code moves all files from `/root/tmp` to `/root/sent`, so after the first file is processed there won't be any files left. You should only move the file you actually processed.

Comment: sure but this runs on an FTP server, so files will constantly be dropped there @mata

Comment: Still, if `os.listdir()` at the top returns for example `['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv']`, then your loop processes `a.csv`, then at the end moves all three files files. So on the next iterations the file `b.csv` will already have been moved without having been sent and you'll get an error while trying to process it because it can't be opened. So `a.csv` has been sent, you may see an error while trying to process `b.csv` and probably don't even realize that `c.csv` whas ever there.